# Without calling function, javascript adding property to object

Tags: javascript, function

```
var jhon = {
                 name : 'Jhon' ,
                 lastName : 'Smith' ,
                 calculateAge : function (){
                                    this.age = 2016 - this.yearOfBirth ;
                                }
            };
```

1. `console.log(jhon)`  => "age" propery not in the o/p
2. jhon.calculateAge();
      console.log(jhon);

   ==> "age" property present in the o/p
3. **(This is what confuse me)**

   console.log(jhon);
   jhon.calculateAge();
   console.log(jhon);

   ===> "age" property present in both the o/p

Can anyone please explain the reason ?

Comment: Where is `this.yearOfBirth` set?